# How to use an if statement with a query result in TCL?

Tags: tcl

The issue that I am having is that I am doing a query to check to see if the order status is processed or completed. I am able to get back the result of query for the order but when I do the if statement it doesn't work as intended.

```
set order_status "select ORDER_STATUS from Customer_Log where order_number = 'xxxxxxx'"
orasql $customer_crsr $order_status 
orafetch $customer_crsr - dataarray hf -indexbyname
set result $hf(ORDER_STATUS)
puts $result

if { ($result == "Completed") || ($result == "Processed) } {
      puts "You can now ship the order"} else {
       puts "Check back again }
```

So in the code above lets say that the $result comes back as "Completed" for some reason the if statement does not work.

Comment: The highlighting seems messed up, and that looks like it is due to unbalaced `"` characters in several places. Does the code work if you fix them? (Use single quotes around string literals in SQL for Oracle; double quotes mean something else.)

Comment: @DonalFellows I changed it to set order_status "select ORDER_STATUS from Customer_Log where order_number = 'xxxxxxx'" and it still does not work...

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? What **precisely** is the value of `$result`? Do `parray hf`

Comment: I see a space between `-` and `dataarray` which is probably a typo. Do you have that in your code?